# In C++ how can I create multiple objects of a class from a file dynamically?

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

I'm still a C++ novice and have been struggling to find any solution to this problem.
I have a file with multiple lines in the format:

[char] [double] [double]

eg:

```
p 100 0.80

r 50 50

p 20 4.8

r -100 25
```

I want to store these lines in objects of class Complex using the name of the line number:

```
class Complex {
private:
    int name;
    char type;
    double a;
    double b;
public:
    Complex(int name, char type, int x, int y);
    char gettype();
    double geta();
    double getb();
};
```

I also want to create them using a custom constructor:

```
Complex::Complex(int name, char type, int x, int y){                    //All data stored in standard form
    if (type = 'p'){
        a = x*cos(y);
        b = x*sin(y);
    }
    else if (type = 'r'){
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}
```

I can split the string into doubles and char but am struggling to store the information. At first I thought I would be able to name them dynamically using a loop but I have heard that instances of a class cannot be created dynamically in C++. I then looked at creating an array but other solutions have stated that this must be done using a default constructor? Is there any way to store this information when I don't know how many lines there will be and using my own constructor?
Also, will the values of a and b generated in the constructor be stored in the object?

Comment: use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: "but I have heard that instances of a class cannot be created dynamically in C++" what? who told you that?

Comment: Books usually contain explanations, several examples, and exercises about this. You should get one.

Comment: @molbdnilo The internet also contains that. He appears to have one already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this would be to store the data in a std::vector, use a constructor that takes a string a splits the input line into the appropriate values, like so:

```
Complex::Complex(int line_no, std::string const& input)
{
   ... Construct complex object using functionality you already know/have ...
}

...
// Process the file
std::ifstream input("inputfile.data");

int line_no = 1;

while (input.is_open() && input.good() && !input.eof())
{
  std::string line;
  std::getline(input, line);

  complex_vector.push_back(Complex(line_no, line));
  ++line_no;
}
```

Comment: This would be so much better if there was another component which did the validation. I think the OP's `Complex` is fine as it is.

Comment: I think that's debatable - from a design perspective, my take on this is that if I want to construct a `Complex` from a line in a file, the knowledge should be embedded into an appropriate constructor for `Complex`. However, there is obviously nothing that would stop anybody from doing away with the additional constructor, put its logic into the body of the loop and then call the original constructor for `Complex` instead.

Comment: Absolutely it is debatable! Its just that I've come down on the side of separating parsing and constructing.  This way the `Complex` class does not change when the source is json or xml or whatever. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. However, now that I've got a vector of objects, when trying to call the vector in a different function it gives the error of _undeclared identifier_. The vector was defined in the main function as `std::vector < Complex > complex_vector;` and called as `double x = complex_vector[name].geta();`

Comment: @Bilderweast You now need to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your constructor goes, you've got `a` and `b` covered. There are two other members you don't yet handle:

```
Complex::Complex(int name, char type, int x, int y): name(name), type(type){
    // a and b handled here
}
```

Also note that your tests for `'p'` and `'r'` should look more like this:

```
if (type == 'p'){  // double equals tests for equality
```